# django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Does anyone know if there are any import or project organization problems?
I have mainly seen views and models to see if there was a problem there but I have no solution [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBpTC.png)

I have tried everything, sorry, I'm just starting with django on my own.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/viJNt.png)

Comment: (a) Do not post your errors as images. (b) You show you're trying to run something in the `web` directory (your app directory). That's wrong. (c) You're doing `from models import ...`; that should be `from web.models import ...`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.